# How to order multiple APKs with native libraries in Google Play Store?

Tags: android-ndk, google-play

My app uses 4 native libraries (armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86, mips). And I uploaded to the Google Play Store in 4 separated APKs with this order of version code:

- armeabi-v7a 104
- armeabi 103
- x86 102
- mips 101

In the Google Play Store, I got this warning message:

```
Some devices with Native platforms containing any of [x86] are eligible to receive version 102, which is better optimized for the device's Native Platform, but actually receive version 104 because it has a higher version code and the device supports Native platforms containing any of [armeabi-v7a] either directly (e.g. ARMv7 devices support a superset of ARMv5TE instructions) or indirectly (e.g. some x86 devices support ARMv7 or ARMv5TE via native code translation). This would occur when 
API levels in range 7+ and 
Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and 
Features containing all of [android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN].
Some devices with Native platforms containing any of [x86] are eligible to receive version 102, which is better optimized for the device's Native Platform, but actually receive version 103 because it has a higher version code and the device supports Native platforms containing any of [armeabi] either directly (e.g. ARMv7 devices support a superset of ARMv5TE instructions) or indirectly (e.g. some x86 devices support ARMv7 or ARMv5TE via native code translation). This would occur when 
API levels in range 7+ and 
Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and 
Features containing all of [android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN].
Some devices are eligible to run multiple APKs. In such a scenario, the device will receive the APK with the higher version code.
```

Is my order of version code is incorrect? And what should be a good order?

Comment: I haven't done this myself, but it seems like giving the x86 version the highest versionCode would be a good idea, if you want to avoid x86 users getting the ARM version and running it with some binary code translator (e.g. libhoudini).

Comment: Why are you separating the ABI's into different APKs when you can upload a single APK with everything together?

Comment: Because the library is too large. It makes a single APK in 65M of size.

Comment: @Michael I will try this.

Comment: @Michael setting highest version code to x86 is better. Only this message remains "Some devices are eligible to run multiple APKs. In such a scenario, the device will receive the APK with the higher version code".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you need to order your ABI as follows:

- armeabi 101
- armeabi-v7a 102
- mips 103
- x86 104

Note: You will still be warned that *Some devices are eligible to run multiple APKs* as it is true, armeabi-v7a devices can also run the armeabi version but will install the APK with the highest version.

It is important to have armeabi (101) as a lower version than armeabi-v7a (102) otherwise your armeabi-v7a devices will install the armeabi version and performance will be poor. Also it is important that x86 is a higher version than armeabi-v7a, as x86 may (or may not) support armeabi-v7a.

You may like to consider adding the ABI code as a prefix to the version (as shown in the chart below). This allows you to release an update for one ABI without having to update all the APKs.

[image: Order of ABI versioning]

These version numbers can be automatically generated in your Android gradle build.

```
project.ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi': 1, 'armeabi-v7a': 2, 'arm64-v8a': 3, 'mips': 5, 'mips64': 6, 'x86': 8, 'x86_64': 9]

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(
                    com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI), 0) * 10000000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
    }
}
```

You can read more about how to implement this versioning system in [this article](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/06/30/android-ndk-version-code-scheme-for-publishing-apks-per-architecture/) I have published.

More information about deploying apps with native libraries can be found [here](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/07/07/android-ndk-a-guide-to-deploying-apps-with-native-libraries/).

Documentation on ABI Splits in the Android build system can be found [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits).